# How do you write a YouTube description for a music clip?

Tags: formatting, social-media

How do you write a YouTube description for a music clip? Is there some kind of conventions? What are some of the conventions and are there templates out there that shows you how to properly credit people and link their video channel in your description and so forth? I am trying to figure out a professional way of doing this, but I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience of seeing music clips on Youtube, you should link where you got the music.

I've seen many song videos, and M.A.P.s, and they always link either channels, or the specific place they got the song and/or art from. I would suggest you watch some music-clips on Youtube and check out their descriptions.

Personally, I've never made a music-clip. This is just based on what I have seen on YouTube.

Good luck with your clip!